# How can I use one field to switch two other fields using joins?

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

This shouldn't be as challenging as it is. I'm trying to use a queried result [codetable] to effectively translate 2 fields in another queried result [CAS] outputted to another result. Is this possible using a single query? It seems like it should be since the 2 fields I'm trying to "translate" are using the same source to decode.

`codetable.Code` is a unique string value, no nulls
`codetable.Decode` is a unique string value, no nulls
`CAS.ID` is a unique identifier, no nulls
`CAS.CodeP` is a non-unique string value, nulls allowed
`CAS.CodeS` is a non unique string value, nulls allowed

[codetable]:

```
Code | Decode
A    | apple
B    | bravo
C    | cat
D    | dog
...  | ...
Z    | zebra
```

[CAS]:

```
ID   | CodeS | CodeP
1    | A     | B
2    | G     | K
3    | P     | R
4    | H     | S
5    | Z     | Y
```

Required Result:

```
ID   | DecodeS| DecodeP
1    | apple  | bravo
2    | golf   | kyoto
3    | peach  | romeo
4    | hello  | sock
5    | zebra  | yellow
```

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    CAS.ID, 
    IIf(CAS.CodeS=codetable.Code, codetable.Decode) AS DecodeS, 
    IIf(CAS.CodeP=codetable.Code, codetable.Decode) AS DecodeP
FROM CAS 
LEFT JOIN codetable ON (CAS.CodeP = codetable.Code) AND (CAS.CodeS = codetable.Code);
```

and got this:

```
ID   | DecodeS| DecodeP
1    | #Error | #Error
2    | #Error | #Error
3    | #Error | #Error
4    | #Error | #Error
5    | #Error | #Error
```

I used an OR operator instead of AND in the join statement (Access didn't like that) but actually got a better result:

```
ID   | DecodeS| DecodeP
1    | #Error | #Error
2    | #Error | #Error
3    | #Error | romeo
4    | hello  | #Error
5    | zebra  | #Error
```

Records producing #Errors in both columns were those with both CodeS and CodeP values being non-null.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.ID
     , CT1.Decode
     , CT2.Decode
FROM CAS C 
LEFT JOIN codetable CT1  ON C.CodeS = CT1.Code 
LEFT JOIN codetable CT2  ON C.CodeP = CT2.Code
```

Comment: In Access 2010, this shows a "syntax error (missing operator)", which suggests that you have to have AND/OR between the join statements

Comment: the query looks fine to me - are you sure you have copied it *exactly* before trying it?

Comment: @M.Ali Could you explain your use of CT1 and CT2 in the SELECT statement? I can't figure out what that's referring to...it's not one of my original tables. Is it some kind of temporary table? Also, where is C.ID coming from? Why not CAS.ID? Thank you

Comment: Without looking at the above code, here's the actual code I'm using:

`SELECT C.CasID,
     CT1.Decode,
     CT2.Decode
FROM SCFIRS_CivilianCAS AS C 
LEFT JOIN SCFIRS_CODETABLE AS CT1  ON CT1.CodeS = C.SpecificLocation
LEFT JOIN SCFIRS_CODETABLE AS CT2  ON CT2.CodeP = C.PrimarySymptom;`

Do you see anything wrong with that? @Bohemian it's still giving me a syntax error (missing operator)